# What is the equivalent of PHP's $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in Java

Tags: java, url, jersey, document-root

I need to know the Java equivalent of PHP's `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

I am writing a Java backend program that will take an uploaded image as a byte[] and save the image to the server where my Java program is running. Then I want to send the image url to the user (front-end) or as email; so that the user can click on the url I send to view the image.

In PHP, I use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` plus the relative path of the file. How do I do that in Java?

I am not using servet. I am using Jersey to return the url. (If that's important)

I need the returned path to be "http://localhost:8080/mypics/pic1.jpg" when the server is localhost and "http://www.mysite.com/mypics/pic1.jpg" when running on a live server. The new File("./") code is not returning "http..."; netbeans cannot find the method ServletContext.getContextPath(), after importing

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ServletContext.getContextPath()` to get context path or use `ServletContext.getRealPath(String path)` to get real path for a given virtual path.

Comment: I am not using servet. I am using Jersey to return the url.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way if you not use servlet API is to create File object point to the ./:

```
System.out.println(new File("./").getAbsolutePath());
```

In this case you should see in console path to your application directory. This could be your `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for this application.

Comment: I need the returned path to be "http://localhost:8080/mypics/pic1.jpg" when the server is localhost and "http://www.mysite.com/mypics/pic1.jpg" when running on a live server. The new File("./") code is not working; the ServletContext.getContextPath() returns not found.